# How to recover corrupt MS Word file?

Tags: microsoft-word, data-recovery, file-recovery, file-corruption

I get this error when I try to open MS Word file.
[image: Word Error]

Got this message when I tried the recovery option.
[image: Recovery results this]

I Googled the error and found couple of recovery software --> [Kernal for Word File Repair](http://www.nucleustechnologies.com/repair-word-file.html) and [Repair My Word](http://www.repairmyword.com/). But both didn't work!

Found [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_other/corrupted-word-2007-file/15af4430-a37d-4543-91dc-701de544d783) in Microsoft community. But when I opened the Word file in Notepad++, there were only 145 columns in Line 2!
[image: Word file opened in Notepad++]

Would love some help to recover my assignment (which is due in two days! )

Comment: Your only option at this point is to restore one of your backup copies.

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't keep a backup!

Comment: Sadly, if you have no backup copies, you have no recovery options

Comment: :-( What could have caused this? I didn't do anything unusual! Worked on the document yesterday, saved it, plugged the pen drive today to finish the work and here I am wondering what the hell happened! This really suck.

Comment: Open Office XML files are actually zip archives, and the error you're seeing when you try to recover is for a file in the zip archive.  You can try renaming the document as a zip archive, opening the particular file (`/word/document.xml`), but I'm not optimistic that you'll be able to repair the file.  Probably create a backup of it first . . .

Comment: Got this trying to open it using WinRAR --> "C:\Users\dell\Desktop\Recovery\MPA 515 Individual Assignment.doc: The archive is either in unknown format or damaged"  
I guess this means I'm doomed.

Comment: It's not possible to determine what happened to your file

Answer (score 1):

#### Search for a backup copy of an unsaved Word 2007 document

- Click the Microsoft Office Button, and then click Word Options.
- In the Navigation Pane, click *Save*.
- In the AutoRecover file location box, note the path, and then click *Cancel*.
- Close Word.
- Open the folder that you noted in step 3.
- Look for files whose names end in .asd (AutoRecover files).

#### Word 2013 Autorecover functionality

1. Open a Word document.
2. Click *File* to go to Backstage View.
3. Go to *Manage Versions* and click on it.
4. Click *Recover unsaved documents*. A dialog box pops up which presents you with list of unsaved documents that can be recovered.
5. Select the document you want to recover.
6. Click *Open*. The unsaved document opens and you are presented with an option to save the document
7. Click *Save As* to save the document.

#### Recover Word document in Google Docs

1. Upload the corrupted Word document to Google Drive.
2. Right-click on the document and select *Open with* -> *Google Docs*. Google Docs will convert the document to its own document format for editing in Google Docs.
3. From the open document in Google Docs select *File* -> *Download as* -> *Microsoft Word (.docx)*. Google Docs will convert the document to .docx format.
4. Open the .docx document that you downloaded from Google Drive in Word.

Google Docs does a good job of converting documents to .docx format. The two file conversions in Google Docs may remove whatever there is in your original Word document that was causing the problem. This method also works for recovering corrupted .odt format documents.

Comment: Can't upload to G Drive. When trying to upload to Google Drive --> "There was an upload error. Dismiss".

Comment: If you upload a copy of the corrupted Word document to any file sharing website (if the document doesn't contain any private information) and provide a link to it in a comment, then I'll upload it to my Google Drive and try to unscramble the document.

Comment: I uploaded it to Dropbox -> https://www.dropbox.com/s/e5rq4mq9g07r5t9/MPA%20515%20Individual%20Assignment.docx?dl=0

Thank you very much for your effort. If this works it will save me from lot of trouble.

Comment: Google Docs returned this message: `Unable to convert document.` I also tried repairing the document with LibreOffice Writer, but it was unable to open the file. XML Copy Editor message was `Cannot open ... conversion from encoding failed.`

Comment: Yes, I also got the same msg. File must be really messed up. But can't figure out what caused this as I didn't do anything out of the ordinary.

Answer (score 0):

#### More options to recover a word doc that will not open

- Try to use Wordpad to open the file.
  This is likely to exclude som features used in the file though, current wordpad can save in *.odt format also - just saving in this non-word format may clean out a problem (Open Document Text, default in e.g. LibreOffice Write).
- The second option is to actually install e.g. LibreOffice and use it to read and recover the document.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

- opening the file in another text editor
- changing the file suffix to `.docx, .txt .odt` (maybe it is not a native `.doc` File)

Comment: OP have shown a picture of the file in Notepad++.

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned DOCX is actually a ZIP file. We can see the ZIP archive signature in the Notepad++ screendump (PK). using below method the file was partially repaired:

- Rename to whatever.ZIP
- Open in WinRAR and pick repair archive option
- Rename back to whatever.docx.

I can now open your file in Libre Office but there's some corruption (for example the image as seen in screenshot):

[image]

Here's the 'repaired' file: [removed], see edit.

EDIT: I now notice the question is years old. No idea why I saw it then, but I will take URL to repaired file down.

Answer (score -2):

If you have accidentally removed files/folder on a computer due to human error or any software issues, you can try a data recovery tool. Check out Disk Drill https://www.cleverfiles.com/word-excel-recovery.html. This program have a lot of good reviews on forums. Or try to read through recovery data software reviews. There are a lot of softwares, you can also find free ones. Though there are several software and tricks to recover lost files, timely backup is the most appropriate way to save your files from accidental loss.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser :) Why do you suggest this one in particular? Please have a quick read of [how do I recommend software in my answers](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers) for some guidance.